# Make ConsoleHandler output appear in logcat output

Tags: android, logcat

Is there anyway to make the output of ConsoleHandler appear in logcat?

I have the following in the code

```
ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
consoleHandler.setFormatter (new DMLogFormatter());
consoleHandler.setLevel (Level.ALL);

FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler ("logFile", true);
fileHandler.setFormatter (new DMLogFormatter());
fileHandler.setLevel (Level.ALL);

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger ("log");
logger.setUseParentHandlers (false);
logger.setLevel (Level.ALL);
logger.addHandler (fileHandler);
logger.addHandler (consoleHandler);
```

The outputs to the FileHandler works fine. Those to the ConsoleHandler does not appear.

I read about the following under 'Viewing stdout and stderr' given in the [Logcat documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat)

> By default, the Android system sends stdout and stderr (System.out and
>   System.err) output to /dev/null. In processes that run the Dalvik VM, you
>   can have the system write a copy of the output to the log file. In this
>   case, the system writes the messages to the log using the log tags stdout
>   and stderr, both with priority I.
>
> To route the output in this way, you stop a running emulator/device
>   instance and then use the shell command setprop to enable the
>   redirection of output. Here's how you do it:
>
> $ adb shell stop
>
> $ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
>
> $ adb shell start

Those three commands did not help as well. Is it possible to make the output of ConsoleHandler appear in Logcat output?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not bound to the `ConsoleHandler`, I recommend using [`slf4j-android`](http://www.slf4j.org/android/) (which dumps to logcat) or [`logback-android`](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/) (which has several options for destination, including a [`LogcatAppender`](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/doc/1.0.0-4/ch/qos/logback/classic/android/LogcatAppender.html)).